# Парсер сайта, написанного на ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, парсер

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите, как можно спарсить информацию с сайта, написанного на ASP.NET. Вся информация подгружается Ajax. Смотрел все обращения к серверу и не нашёл ни одного файла, который содержал бы данные. Одни js скрипты, пару файлов .axd и картинки.

При переходе на, допустим 2-ую страницу, в ссылке ничего не отображается. На ссылке со второй страницей висит запуск скрипта js.

В общем в какую сторону копать и где искать ссылку на источник информации.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com).

загружаете код нужной вам страницы

```
WebClient web = new WebClient();
string htmlStr = web.DownloadString("АДРЕС");
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(htmlStr);
```

А дальше, используя XPath или LINQ, получаете нужную информацию из объекта `doc`.